# Recording Siebel VUgen Script

Tags: internet-explorer, recording, loadrunner, siebel

I've got 2 problems with recording  VUGen script.
**My configuration:**

1. Load Runner 11.00
2. Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
3. Windows XP Professional SP 3, I5-2500K CPU @ 3.30 GHz, 2.91 Gb RAM

I use **Siebel – web protocol.** Our application uses https protocol.

```
VUGen Recording options  are:
General-Script:
Generate think time greater than threshold = 3, checked
Track processes created as COM local servers
General – Protocols:
    Siebel –Web
General – Recording:
    HTML-based script
        Advanced- Script type = A script containing explicit URLs only
        Advanced – Non HTML generated elements =Do not record
Network
    Port Mapping
        Capture level = WinINET level data
HTTP Properties – Advanced
    Save snapshot resources locally checked
    Support charset = UTF-8 
HTTP Properties –Correlation
    Siebel correlation checked
```

**The first problem is:**
    When recording script on my host machine there are a lot of events (about 800 from login only). I comparing it with my virtual machine and with my coleagues hosts.

This is the sample of my host:

```
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1714)] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1714)] Load Network Traffic Analyzers:
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1714)]     Analyzer Module: Siebel_Web (value=)
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1714)]     Analyzer Module: local_server (value=)
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1714)] ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)] Address lookup for wks03 = 172.31.86.25
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1738)] Address lookup for wks03 = 172.31.86.25
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1738)] Request Connection: Remote Server @ 192.168……..   (Service=)  (Sid=  1)  PROXIED!
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Client -> Server : 77 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 1380 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 66 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Client -> Server : 182 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 43 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Client -> Server : 325 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 377 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Client -> Server : 328 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 1746 bytes 
[WinInet Request  ( bf8: d08)] GET "https://bcvm168/fins_rus"
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Client -> Server : 626 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 642 bytes 
[Network Analyzer ( bf8:1158)]   (Sid:  1) Server -> Client : 2020 bytes 
[WinInet Request  ( bf8: d08)] GET "https://bcvm168/fins_rus/start.swe?SWECmd=Start&SWEHo=bcvm168"
```

**This is the sample of my virtual machine:**

```
[WinInet Request  ( 86c: 8cc)] GET "https://bcvm168/fins_rus/files/main.css"
[WinInet Request  ( 86c: 8cc)] GET "https://bcvm168/fins_rus/23016/scripts/login.js"
[WinInet Request  ( 86c: 8cc)] GET https://bcvm168/fins_rus/23016/scripts/swecommon_top.js
```

**I don't know how to turn off this Network Analyzer.**

The second problem is an issue with recording drilldown action:

- I am trying to record drilldown using portmapping = wininet
  This attempt fails: recorded a lot of events (about 3000) after this the IE tab recovers and nothing else records.
- When I'm trying to use port-mapping Socket, drilldown  doesn't fails, but nothing recording.
  Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a mentor to assist you locally as you are asking to turn off items which are core to the product's capability to record.  This would suggest that you have been dumped into this role with little to no training on the tools you are using.

If the observation above is true and you are being asked to deliver without training in tools, processes or a mentor for a period of time which could be as long as a year (depending upon your foundation skills) then you should be aware that this path has nearly a 100% failure rate and that it is your management to blame for your predicament.

Comment: James, thank you for your replay, my mentor helps me too, but I prefer to try more than one way to solve my problems. Do you have any practical advices for me?

Comment: Attend formal product training with an HP certified instructor using HP provided materials

Answer (score 0):

Well, some practical experience gave me a "cheating way". This problem solved by switching between different processes of Windows when attempting to record script. For example, if app cashes when I recording the button click, i clicking it and minimize the window with app, after 10-20 seconds the step is recorded.

Answer (score -1):

are you able to traverse the flow manually on your machine? 
If not check- 
all the sieble related high interactive objects are loaded with IE.
C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files

and URL is added as a trusted site in IE. (Internet option- security Tab)
plus- enable activeX contorls and plugins (Internet option- security Tab- custom level)

change recording setting in LR- 
Portmapping = Socket level data

Hope this help!!

Comment: hi! I've done this options before posted this question, because it's standart settings for siebel work. Unfortunately, it doesn't work still. Even for hp lr11.00 patches didn't help....Thank you for replay. May be you have some other ideas?